# O comando chmod não funciona como esperado quando uso o MINGW32

Tags: windows, sistema-de-arquivos, mingw

O comando `chmod` não funciona como esperado quando uso o **MINGW32** no Windows.

Testei apenas no Windows 10 64 bits.

```
$ cat ~/bin/minha-shell
echo "Esta é minha shell"
ls -lat /c/

$ chmod 777 ~/bin/minha-shell

$ ls -lat ~/bin/minha-shell
-rw-r--r-- 1 user Administradores 38 Nov  6 14:08 /c/Users/user//bin/minha-shell

$ minha-shell
sh.exe": minha-shell: command not found
```

No Linux isso funciona

Alguma dica ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O MINGW funciona ligeiramente diferente que uma distribuição linux.

Ele requer um Shebang no inicio da Shell para alterar o atributo do arquivo.

```
$ cat ~/bin/minha-shell
#!/bin/bash
echo "Esta é minha shell"
ls -lat /c/

$ chmod 777 ~/bin/minha-shell
```

Assim deve funcionar !